# R iteration over files from different directory

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data in different folders that I need to import and transform in a loop using purr. The path and names of the csv files follow the pattern below:

```
data/csd-alberta/
data/csd-ontario/
data/csd-pei/
data/csd-bc/

# for all of the province

c(alberta, bc, newbruns, newfoundland, nova, nunavut, nw, ont, pei, qc, sask, yukon)
```

There are many csv files in each province folder, but the main dataset I want to import starts with 98. For example:

```
# note that all data sets must begin with 98 and end with .csv. 

csd_alberta_raw <- read_csv("csd-alberta/98-1.csv")
csd_bc_raw <- read_csv("csd-bc/98-2.csv")
csd_ont_raw <- read_csv("csd-ont/98-3.csv")
```

There are other csv files in the folder so I only need to import these that start with 98.

I would like to use purr and `map_df` to integrate the data transformation for all the files, since they all have the same columns and require the same data cleaning. But I'm not sure how to do this for all of the directory, and also specify the pattern for the csv.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following :

- Use `list.files` to get the complete path of the filenames in all the folders with a specific pattern (`'^98.*\\.csv$'`).
- Use `map_df` to read the all the files and combine them. I have also included a new column called `file` which will identify the file from which data is coming from.

```
filenames <- list.files('data/', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = '^98.*\\.csv$')
combine_data <- purrr::map_df(filenames, readr::read_csv, .id = 'file')
```